# Grouping pixels into clusters based on pixel value in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.0

I have a raster image with different pixel values, each pixel values represent number of persons living in that pixel. I want all the pixels with population which are nearby to be clustered into one group.

How can i do this?

The image which should be clustered looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure, you want a summary of values at a larger granularity? Have a look at [Focal Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/focal-statistics.htm) and use the "Sum" to aggregate values based on a specific distance.

Comment: Region group will do. Reclassify first to 0,1